# Foundation close alerts after 3 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript, zurb-foundation

I want to close all alert-box items on a page after 3 seconds. I could just do

```
window.setTimeout ( ->
    $('.alert-box').remove()
    return
), 3000
```

But that does not do the same as clicking the x button in an alert. It does not animate it. And since it has been written somewhere I would not like to rewrite it.

I tried

```
$('.alert-box').data('events')
```

to find the registered handlers and maybe find the method to close an alert with animation and such, but no luck with that. I also tried the FireQuery plugin, however, that also did not do the job.

I was hoping there is some method for closing an alert like

```
Foundation.alert.close(jQuery object)
```

or something can you help me out with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your alert boxes have a close anchor element, you could try doing:

```
$(".alert-box a.close").click();
```

This is more or less what the [official tests do](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/blob/master/spec/alert/alert.js?source=cc). However, this doesn't seem to be very reliable. [The code](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/blob/master/js/foundation/foundation.alert.js) is actually listening to ´click.fndtn.alert´ on ´[alert] a.close´.

```
$(".alert-box a.close").trigger("click.fndtn.alert")
```

Answer (score 2):

thanks for sharing! This is exactly I looked for.

In order to make closing more user friendly I've added **`$(".alert-box").slideUp();`** i.e. resulting code:

```
$(document).ready ->
  window.setTimeout ( ->
      $(".alert-box").slideUp();
      $(".alert-box a.close").click();
      return
  ), 15000
```